# setting value in array list from Map

Tags: java, elasticsearch, arraylist

Am fetching records from elasticsearch and am trying to return as a list. But am getting error while adding to the list from `sourceAsMap`

Please find my code below.

```
SearchHit[] searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();
    List<Product> productList=new ArrayList<Product>();
    for (SearchHit hit : searchHits) {
        // get each hit as a Map

        Map<String, Object> sourceAsMap = hit.getSourceAsMap();
        product=new Product();
        product.setName(sourceAsMap.get("name").toString());
        productList.add(product.setName(sourceAsMap.get("name").toString()));  // throwing error in this line

    }

    return productList;
}
```

Please find my POJO class:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Product {

    private String id;
    private String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are getting `The method add(void) is undefined for the type Product`.Your `Product#setName` methods return type is `void`, so you are actually trying to add `void` to `List` of `Product`. You should do `productList.add(product)` instead of `productList.add(product.setName(sourceAsMap.get("name").toString()));`

Your code should looks like below:

```
    Map<String, Object> sourceAsMap = hit.getSourceAsMap();
    product=new Product();
    product.setName(sourceAsMap.get("name").toString());
    productList.add(product);
```

Comment: I have added my POJO class too. to which method i have to change the return type as `void` to `List`..?

Comment: @Karthikeyan You don't need to change anything only use `productList.add(product)` instead of `productList.add(product.setName(sourceAsMap.get("name").toString()));` wil solve your problem